# Linq Query with multiple joins and multiple conditions

Tags: linq, join, telerik

I am using Telerik Data Access to perform OR mapping.

I am trying to use Linq for performing a join query but not sure how to proceed correctly.

The original *sql* query is given by:

```
'SELECT O.OPS_LEG_ID, O.ATD_DATE, O.DEP_AIRPORT_ACT, O.ARR_AIRPORT_ACT, O.ATA_DATE,  '+
                          'O.FL_LOG_ATD_DATE, O.FL_LOG_ATA_DATE, O.FL_LOG_DEP_AIRPORT, O.FL_LOG_ARR_AIRPORT, '+
                          'O.FL_NB, O.DESIGNATOR, O.FL_LOG_ID, O.FL_LOG_STATUS '+
                          'FROM CREW_ROT_ROLE CR, OPS_LEG O, CREW_ROLES R, CREW_PAIRING_CMP CP '+
                          'WHERE CR.ROLE_CDE = R.ROLE_CDE '+
                            'AND CR.CREW_ROTATION_ID = CP.CREW_ROTATION_ID '+
                            'AND CP.OPS_LEG_ID = O.OPS_LEG_ID '+
                            'AND CR.CREW_CDE = :CREW_CDE '+
                            'AND O.ATD_DATE >= :D_FROM '+
                            'AND O.ATD_DATE <= :D_TO '+
                            //'AND R.ROLE_TYPE = 0 '+
                          'ORDER BY O.ATD_DATE
```

The corresponding Entities have been generated from the SQL tables. I am now trying to build the equivalent Linq query, which does not seem to work:

```
var results = from opsLeg in dbContext.OPS_LEGs
                              from crewRotationRole in dbContext.CREW_ROT_ROLEs
                              from crewRole in dbContext.CREW_ROLEs
                              from crewPairingComponent in dbContext.CREW_PAIRING_CMPs
                              where crewRotationRole.ROLE_CDE == crewRole.ROLE_CDE
                              && crewRotationRole.CREW_ROTATION_ID == crewPairingComponent.CREW_ROTATION_ID
                              && crewPairingComponent.OPS_LEG_ID == opsLeg.OPS_LEG_ID
                              && crewRotationRole.CREW_CDE == userId
                              select new { OpsLegId = opsLeg.OPS_LEG_ID,
                                           Designator = opsLeg.DESIGNATOR,
                                           FlightNumber = opsLeg.FL_NB
                                         };
```

Trying the previous query, raises an exception:

> "Identifier 'ROLE_CDE' is not a parameter or variable or field of
>   'FlightLogEntities.OPS_LEG'. If 'ROLE_CDE' is a property please add
>   the FieldAlias or Storage attribute to it or declare it as a field's
>   alias."

Not sure how to proceed. What would be the correct query using Linq joins? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ORM like Entity framework, then the **conceptual model would be mix of classes, which would provide a object centric view of data.**

So, you would be using the Linq on Objects and in that case you need not write queries for joins as we do in SQL for a database. Conceptual model would contain objects which would be having **relationships** using **navigational** properties, and to access navigational properties you can access them as a property of object.

For e.g if there are 2 tables in Database, Customer & Orders. Following SQL statement will return all Orders for Customer number 1:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
Where Customers.CustomerID = 1
```

If we use the EF to generate to generate the conceptual model from Database, we would get class for Customer and Order and Customer class would have a property of ICollection. So, if you need the same results as the SQL query above, you would do it in following way

```
var CustomerOne = context.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerID == 1);
var ordersForCustomerOne = CustomerOne.Orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
var k = from r in dataContext.Order_Details
        join t in dataContext.Orders on r.OrderID equals t.OrderID
        select r.OrderID   ;
```